# C++ Qt MingW bad reloc 0xc address in section rdata

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, mingw

I'm with Qt 5.5 on Windows 10 64 bit with MingW compiler.
I'm trying to compile my project in debug mode => Works perfectly
But in release mode, I have these errors:

```
undefined reference to `TileMap::XYToNode(int, int) const'
undefined reference to `TileMap::XYToNode(int, int) const'  
./release\perso.o: bad reloc address 0xc in section `.rdata'  
collect2.exe:-1: erreur : error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried to do clean, qmake, and rebuild, but there are still errors.
I use some SFML dlls, and dlls I created. My TileMap class inherits a SFML class, and a micropather class (which is in one of the dlls).

*Yes, I have tried Google before.*

The .pro file:

```
    TEMPLATE = app  
    TARGET = TealDemo  
    QT = widgets  

SOURCES += ........  

LIBS += -LC:/Qt/5.5/SFML/lib -LC:/Qt/5.5/micropather/lib -LC:/Qt/5.5/pathstore/lib

CONFIG(release): LIBS += -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-main -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lmp -lpathstore  
CONFIG(debug): LIBS += -lsfml-graphics-d -lsfml-main-d -lsfml-window-d -lsfml-system-d -lmpd -lpathstored  

INCLUDEPATH += C:/Qt/5.5/SFML/include C:/Qt/5.5/micropather/include C:/Qt/5.5/pathstore/include  
DEPENDPATH += C:/Qt/5.5/SFML/include C:/Qt/5.5/micropather/include C:/Qt/5.5/pathstore/include  

HEADERS += .......

CONFIG += C++11 warn_on  

debug {  
    DEFINES += TEAL_DEBUG  
}
```

How to resolve this ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you compared the link commandlines? If this works in one configuration but not the other (debug vs release) there has to be some difference between these.

Comment: I added .pro file, and, I haven't compared commandlines yet. I'll do it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted the inline before the function in the .cpp file, and it worked... Such strange.

Comment: You had it declared normally in the header then implemented int in the `.cpp` file as `inline`?  I don't think it's strange at all that a release build would have a problem with that scenario. `inline` functions need to have the definition included in all translation units that might call it.