# build openCV & Qt project and link error:undefined reference and bad reloc address 0x1 in section

Tags: qt, opencv, cmake, mingw

I have built the release version of openCV 4.5.1 shared library with CMake 3.91.2 & MinGW-W64 GCC-6.4.0 i686-posix-dwarf with default compile config.
Tried to use the libraries with Qt 5.4 & MinGW 4.9.1 32 bit.
I'm in Windows 10 64 bit.

Here's my `.pro`:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test05
TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include

LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/opencv -lopencv_highgui451.dll -lopencv_core451.dll -lopencv_imgcodecs451.dll -lopencv_imgproc451.dll
```

Here's `main.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Mat image = imread("D:\\test.jpg");
    namedWindow("window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("window",image);
    waitKey(0);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Here's build output:

```
E:\workspace\test05\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
E:\workspace\test05\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
E:\workspace\test05\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
:-1: error: release/main.o: bad reloc address 0x1 in section `.text$_ZN7cvflann7anyimpl21typed_base_any_policyIbE4typeEv[__ZN7cvflann7anyimpl21typed_base_any_policyIbE4typeEv]'
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have googled a lot,these two questions seems close to my situation but could not solve my problem:

- [Undefined reference to cv::imread(std::string const&, int)](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13000)
- [C++ Qt MingW bad reloc 0xc address in section rdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694482/c-qt-mingw-bad-reloc-0xc-address-in-section-rdata)

EDIT:
Thank for your advice,I deleted the GUI part and tried these:

```
LIBS += E:\workspace\test05\lib\opencv\libopencv_core451.dll.a
```

```
LIBS += E:\workspace\test05\lib\opencv\libopencv_core451.dll
```

Both don't work,the issues keep the same as above.I don't know if I built the shared library correctly or it's a simple link error?

Comment: Can you delete the below part of `waitKey(0)` it belongs to gui part of qt and looks weird and not safe to use in there. and [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/204895/undefined-reference-to-cvimshowcvstring-const-cv_inputarray-const-with-qt58/) is also your answer.

Comment: you are following bad advice. LIBS += ... does *not* take ".dll" files. it takes .lib files. the `-l` flag of gcc's linker is ONLY for lib files. finding dlls is a runtime thing. you are already failing at link time. there's that wiki page where someone stated this wrongly.

Comment: So you're mixing c++ code of different gcc versions 4.9.1 and 6.4.0? I don't think that's (always) possible.

Comment: gcc 4.9.1 can't build opencv4,it seems like it has bug so I have to update the version of gcc to built opencv.But I have to use gcc 4.9.1 in my project due to my company.PS:the debug version of library I built works.Issues only occurs in the release version.

Comment: Those are all really old GCC compilers. I was able to build OpenCV 4.5.1 with MinGW-w64 GCC 10.2.0 from http://winlibs.com/

Comment: hmm,maybe I should use VS to develop new code about opencv then export it as a DLL,if it's really caused by compiler